# Duplicating view issue using Cocoa for OS X, Xcode 9.3, Swift 4.1

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am new to programming and trying to learn Cocoa for Mac OS using Xcode 9.3 and Swift 4.1.  I’ve worked through books on C++ and Objective-C.  Now I am working through the Big Nerd Ranch book, Cocoa Programming for Mac OS, 5th edition which uses Swift 2.0 (on my own). There have been challenges trying to work through the differences from Swift 2.0 to 4.1, and I don’t know if this issue if part of that.

To sum up the exercise, I created a die. Part of the exercise is to make the die change its number by double clicking in the die.  I did that, and it worked.  Now I need to duplicate the die twice for a total of three dice.

I followed the steps to copy the die (highlight the dieView and command-D) and I now have three dice. Each view accepts First Responder and each view subsequently accepts keyboard input to change the number showing on the die.  I can select the key window with the mouse and the highlight shows which window is active. However, the double-click to “roll” the dice only works on the original die, not the other two. How can that be when they are exact duplicates? And since they were copied, how can I get the double-click to work in the other two dice since they should have the same code?

I also tried moving the original die to the third position, moving the two new dice over and now it is still the die in the first position that works with the double-click, not the last two in line. When I move the dice into a stacked position, one above the other, above the other, at first I had them on the left side of the window, and the double-click did not work on any of them. I resized the window so they were all stacked on the left side, and the double-click only works on the bottom die.

I know this has something to do with the custom view window the dice are in, but shouldn’t mouse clicks register anywhere in that window? Obviously the clicks are being registered, because I can change the key window to each of the dice. It’s just the double-click feature that isn’t working correctly.

Here is my dieView code:

```
import Cocoa

@IBDesignable class DieView: NSView {

    var intValue: Int? = 1 {
        didSet {
            needsDisplay = true
        }
    }

    var pressed: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            needsDisplay = true
        }
    }

    var dieShape = NSBezierPath()

    override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
        return NSSize(width: 20, height: 20)
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let backgroundColor = NSColor.lightGray
        backgroundColor.set()
        NSBezierPath.fill(bounds)
        drawDieWithSize(size: bounds.size)
    }

    func metricsForSize(size: CGSize) -> (edgeLength: CGFloat, dieFrame: CGRect) {
        let edgeLength = min(size.width, size.height)
        let padding = edgeLength/10.0
        let drawingBounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: edgeLength, height: edgeLength)
        var dieFrame = drawingBounds.insetBy(dx: padding, dy: padding)
        if pressed {
            dieFrame = dieFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -edgeLength/40)
        }
        return (edgeLength, dieFrame)
    }

    func drawDieWithSize(size: CGSize) {
        if let intValue = intValue {
            let (edgeLength, dieFrame) = metricsForSize(size: size)
            let cornerRadius:  CGFloat = edgeLength/5.0
            let dotRadius = edgeLength/12.0
            let dotFrame = dieFrame.insetBy(dx: dotRadius * 2.5, dy: dotRadius * 2.5)

            // The glint must be within the dot.
            let glintFrame = dotFrame

            NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()

            let shadow = NSShadow()
            shadow.shadowOffset = NSSize(width: 0, height: -1)
            //shadow.shadowBlurRadius = edgeLength/20
            shadow.shadowBlurRadius = (pressed ? edgeLength/100 : edgeLength/20)
            shadow.set()

            // Draw the rounded shape of the die profile:
            // Challenge use color Gradient - commented portions are used to make white die and were removed to make code more readable in this post
            let gradient = NSGradient(starting: NSColor.red, ending: NSColor.blue)
            dieShape =
                NSBezierPath(roundedRect: dieFrame, xRadius: cornerRadius, yRadius: cornerRadius)
            gradient?.draw(in: dieShape, angle: 1.0)

            // Challlenge - use stroke() to add a border the die
            NSColor.black.set()
            dieShape.lineWidth = 4
            dieShape.stroke()

            NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()
            // Shadow will not apply to subequent drawing commands

            // ready to draw the dots.
            // Nested Function to make drawing dots cleaner:
            func drawDot(u: CGFloat, v: CGFloat) {
                let dotOrigin = CGPoint(x: dotFrame.minX + dotFrame.width * u,
                                        y: dotFrame.minY + dotFrame.height * v)
                let dotRect =
                    CGRect(origin: dotOrigin, size: CGSize.zero).insetBy(dx: -dotRadius, dy: -dotRadius)
                // The dots will be black:
                NSColor.black.set()
                NSBezierPath(ovalIn: dotRect).fill()
                }


            // nested function to draw a glint in each dot
            func drawGlint(u: CGFloat, v: CGFloat) {
                let glintOrigin = CGPoint(x: glintFrame.minX + glintFrame.width * u,
                                          y: glintFrame.minY + glintFrame.height * v)
                let glintRect =
                    CGRect(origin: glintOrigin,
                           size: CGSize(width: 3.5, height: 3.5)).insetBy(dx: -0.5, dy: -0.5)

                // Glints will be white
                NSColor.white.set()
                NSBezierPath(rect: glintRect).fill()
            }

            // If intVlaue is in range...
            if intValue >= 1 && intValue <= 6 {
                // Draw the dots:
                if intValue == 1 || intValue == 3 || intValue == 5 {
                    drawDot(u: 0.5, v: 0.5)     // Center dot
                    drawGlint(u: 0.55, v: 0.55)
                }
                if intValue >= 2 && intValue <= 6 {
                    drawDot(u: 0, v: 1)     // upper left
                    drawGlint(u: 0.05, v: 1.05)
                    drawDot(u: 1, v: 0)     // Lower right
                    drawGlint(u: 1.05, v: 0.05)
                }
                if intValue >= 4 && intValue <= 6 {
                    drawDot(u: 1, v: 1)     // Upper right
                    drawGlint(u: 1.05, v: 1.05)
                    drawDot(u: 0, v: 0)     // lower left
                    drawGlint(u: 0.05, v: 0.05)
                }
                if intValue == 6 {
                    drawDot(u: 0, v: 0.5)   // Mid left/right
                    drawGlint(u: 0.05, v: 0.55)
                    drawDot(u: 1, v: 0.5)
                    drawGlint(u: 1.05, v: 0.55)
                }
            } else {
                let paraStyle = NSParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
                paraStyle.alignment = .center
                let font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: edgeLength * 0.5)
                let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: NSColor.black,
                    NSAttributedStringKey.font : font,
                    NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paraStyle ]
                let string = "\(intValue)" as NSString
                string.drawCentered(in: dieFrame, attributes: attrs)

            }
        }
    }

    func randomize() {
        intValue = Int(arc4random_uniform(5)) + 1
    }

    // MARK: - Mouse Events

    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        if dieShape.contains(event.locationInWindow) {
            Swift.print("mouseDown CLICKCOUNT: \(event.clickCount)")
            let dieFrame = metricsForSize(size: bounds.size).dieFrame
            let pointInView = convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
            pressed = dieFrame.contains(pointInView)
        }
    }

    override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
        Swift.print("mouseDragged")
    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        if dieShape.contains(event.locationInWindow) {
            Swift.print("mouseUp clickCount: \(event.clickCount)")
            if event.clickCount == 2 {
                randomize()
            }
            pressed = false
        }
    }

    // MARK: - First Responder

    override func drawFocusRingMask() {
        NSBezierPath.fill(bounds)
    }

    override var focusRingMaskBounds: NSRect {
        return bounds
    }

    override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { return true }

    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // MARK: Ketboard Events

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        interpretKeyEvents([event])
    }

    override func insertText(_ insertString: Any) {
        let text = insertString as! String
        if let number = Int(text) {
            intValue = number
        }
    }

    override func insertTab(_ sender: Any?) {
        window?.selectNextKeyView(sender)
    }

    override func insertBacktab(_ sender: Any?) {
        window?.selectPreviousKeyView(sender)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick glance, my guess is the problem is in `if dieShape.contains(event.locationInWindow)`.

`diaShape` is in local (view) coordinate. But `event.locationInWindow` is in window coordinates. You need to first convert the window coordinates into local coordinates before you can test the hit point.

Refer to the documentation for `locationInWindow`:

```
let eventLocation = event.locationInWindow
let localPoint = self.convert(eventLocation, from: nil)
if dieShape.contains(localPoint)
   ...
```

If your view is close to the origin of the window, the difference between window and view coordinates is small enough that it might work, but the ones further away won't.

Comment: Thanks James!  I should have known to go to the documentation for locationInWindow.  And I should have known that Window is not View!  I made the corrections in mouseDown and mouseUp and it is working as it should now.  Thank you for your help. - Joel

Comment: And if you find an answer useful, up-vote it and/or mark it as the correct answer. This helps people in the future with a similar problem find solutions.